# Order by same input where in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, case

For my project I'm using `sqlite` normally I use mysql. In mysql I would make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM breeds where id in (2, 1, 4) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2, 1, 4) ASC
```

I need to order by the `where in ids`. How can I get the same result in sqlite because `FIELD` is not working in sqlite?

Comment: Use INSTR(), for example... posession in the list and substring start are relative the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a string which is a comma separated list of the ids, like `'2,1,4'` then you can use the function `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT * FROM breeds 
WHERE id IN (2, 1, 4) 
ORDER BY INSTR(',' || '2,1,4' || ',', ',' || id || ',')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression - basically that's what MySQL's `field()` function does:

```
select *
from breeds
where id in (2, 1, 4)
order by case id
    when 2 then 1
    when 1 then 2
    when 4 then 3
end
```